# Iterate Json and get last elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i want to iterate json to get last element. I have tried to find the json length but length is showing 296 something.there is something i don't know ..how to iterate.

Iterate **Json** and get last elements `id: 005 and text: GHI`. I am trying to do in this way.

**JQuery**

```
  var json= ( JSON.stringify($(target).select2('data')) );
     alert(selections.length);    

     $.each($.parseJSON(json), function(key,value){
            var id = this.id;
            var text = this.text;
            console.log(id +"   "+text);
    });
```

**JSON**

```
  [
      {
        "id": "001",
        "text": "DEF",
        "element": [
          {

          }
        ],
        "disabled": false,
        "locked": false
      },
      {
        "id": "002",
        "text": "JKL",
        "element": [
          {

          }
        ],
        "disabled": false,
        "locked": false
      },
      {
        "id": "003",
        "text": "MNO",
        "element": [
          {

          }
        ],
        "disabled": false,
        "locked": false
      },
      {
        "id": "004",
        "text": "ABC",
        "element": [
          {

          }
        ],
        "disabled": false,
        "locked": false
      },
      {
        "id": "005",
        "text": "GHI",
        "element": [
          {

          }
        ],
        "disabled": false,
        "locked": false
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Why stringify to JSON only to turn right back around and parse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Store your JSON in a variable
2. Make use of `varName.length-1` to reach the last element in the array

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LcUwk/)**

```
var json = [{
    "id": "001",
    "text": "DEF",
    "element": [{

    }],
    "disabled": false,
    "locked": false
}, {
    "id": "002",
    "text": "JKL",
    "element": [{

    }],
    "disabled": false,
    "locked": false
}, {
    "id": "003",
    "text": "MNO",
    "element": [{

    }],
    "disabled": false,
    "locked": false
}, {
    "id": "004",
    "text": "ABC",
    "element": [{

    }],
    "disabled": false,
    "locked": false
}, {
    "id": "005",
    "text": "GHI",
    "element": [{

    }],
    "disabled": false,
    "locked": false
}];

var $last = json[json.length - 1];
alert($last.id);
alert($last.text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a Javascript array. Using length to get the last index will indeed work:

```
var json = JSON.stringify( $(target).select2('data') );
var lastObject = json[json.length - 1];

var id = lastObject.id;
var text = lastObject.text;

console.log( id + " " + text );
```

Remember that indexes start with 0, so you must subtract 1 from the length to get the desired index.

Answer (score -1):

`var h = [
      {
        "id": "001",
        "text": "DEF",
        "element": [
          {
          }
        ],
        "disabled": false,
        "locked": false
      },
      {
        "id": "002",
        "text": "JKL",
        "element": [
          {
          }
        ],
        "disabled": false,
        "locked": false
      },
      {
        "id": "003",
        "text": "MNO",
        "element": [
          {
          }
        ],
        "disabled": false,
        "locked": false
      },
      {
        "id": "004",
        "text": "ABC",
        "element": [
          {
          }
        ],
        "disabled": false,
        "locked": false
      },
      {
        "id": "005",
        "text": "GHI",
        "element": [
          {
          }
        ],
        "disabled": false,
        "locked": false
      }
    ];`

```
var len = h.length;
console.log(len);               //prints 5
console.log(h[len-1].id);       //prints 005
console.log(h[len-1].text);     //prints GHI
```